# What does dotenv().ok() do?

Tags: rust, rust-result

I am using the Diesel ORM wrapper with PostgreSQL. I was following [the guide on their website](http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/) which has the following code:

```
pub fn establish_connection() -> PgConnection {
     dotenv().ok();

     let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL")
         .expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
     PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
         .expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
}
```

I understood what `dotenv()` does through the dotenv docs — it loads the env file. In the source code I saw that that `dotenv()` returns a `Result`. What does `ok()` do then? Does it unwrap the result? If so, why not use `unwrap()`?

Comment: see [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) for the standard lib version. diesel's will probably be defined in terms of that. The [ok method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) will probably do the same. `unwrap` can `panic`, but `ok` can't, so the caller can handle the failure case

Comment: @joelb Note that the use of `ok()` is not for handling the failure case, it's for **ignoring** the failure case. When handling failure, one would not typically call `ok()` (because it throws away the error information), but match the returned `Result` directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a way to ignore errors arising from failing to load the dotenv environment file.

`dotenv()` returns a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html). [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) converts the `Result` into an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). This `Option` does not trigger the warning about an unused `Result`.

> why not use `unwrap()`

Because you don't want it to fail. In production, you should *not* have an environment file, instead you will use actual environment variables. If you `unwrap`ped, then your service would fail in production immediately. This has happened to me, unfortunately.

Comment: Would you consider it good practice to use `ok()` to silence the warning in production code? It seems like it will also silently ignore e.g. syntax error in the file (in case of the [`LineParse`](https://docs.rs/dotenv/0.15.0/dotenv/enum.Error.html#variant.LineParse) variant of the error result), or system errors other than "file not found" (e.g. not being able to read the file due to invalid permissions) and which you might want to know about.

Comment: @user4815162342 in _general_ no, I don't think it's good to ignore errors this way. For `dotenv`, ignoring errors seems acceptable as the negative outcomes should only happen in development, where the stakes are lower.

Comment: I see what you mean, the idea is that it's a non-problem in production. I wonder if a document as widely used (and copied/cited) as Diesel guide should be promoting the pattern. Perhaps it should at least display the error, as with `dotenv().map_err(|e| eprintln!("dotenv: {}", e)).ok()`. (I'm not sure if that will print an error when the file is not present.) If there is agreement as to a better idiom (if any), I can send them a PR to change the guide.

Comment: @user4815162342 A problem I foresee is that Diesel doesn't want to concentrate on dotenv, but rather on the Diesel-specific code. Making the error handling for dotenv longer would distract from that purpose. A different path would be to modify dotenv so that "fatal" errors are reported as such and "warning" errors can be ignored. That has the downside of requiring the library to have an opinion on what is / isn't fatal.